# Is it possible to add a mass quick action/button to Account listview to create a Note?

Tags: list-view, quickaction, notes, list-button

I created a new quick action to *Add a Note* on the Account object, but even though I go to the Search layout/List this action is not available there.

Is it possible to do this? I would like to select several Accounts in the listview and add the same Note to them all in one go, rather than each one individually.

Answer (score 0):

Create vf page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" 
           sidebar="false"
           standardController="Account"
           recordSetVar="accounts"
           extensions="pocAccountController"
           action="{!retrieveSelectedAccounts}">

    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selectedAccounts}" var="acc"  >
            <apex:column value="{!acc.Name}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

`recordSetVar` will tell that it can be used in list button. Now apex extension class:

```
public class pocAccountController {

    private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;
    public List<Account> selectedAccounts{get;set;}

    public pocAccountController(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController){
        this.standardController = standardController;
    }

    public PageReference retrieveSelectedAccounts()
    {       
        Map<Id,Account> selectedAccountsMap = new Map<Id,Account> ((List<Account>)standardController.getSelected());
        selectedAccounts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id=:selectedAccountsMap.keySet()];
        System.debug('selectedAccounts => '+selectedAccounts);
        return null;        
    }

}
```

`retrieveSelectedAccounts` is invoked directly on page. Now create a list button.

[image]

Then add it in search layout:

[image]

Now button is visible in list layout (any other list view except `Recently viewed`).

[image]

Clicking on it will get selected accounts:

[image]

List button can send selected records only to visualforce page currently. If you need to show lightning component, then you can use pageReference URL (`lightning/cmp/c__myComponent`) and pass the records Ids as parameters